# Why sometimes we use NgModule and sometimes pure Components Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one question about Angular 2. I was working with it till RC4. Now I saw that major concepts was added (NgModule). I am trying to work with that but I don't understand why we use sometimes Module and sometimes only Component.

For example. Why we use Components instead Module? Why we didn't create NgModule wrapper for Crisis Center and navigate to it? I don't understand.

From official doc I uderstand that *every logic unit should be different module that can be created via NgModule*.   Okay, no problem.

But after that I see that we just use pure components. I don't understand when I should use Module concept and when Component.  I can't use module for routing?

But if I have many services/childComponents/pipes etc. in some component that I want to render on some path, so in that case should I create standard providers/directives  decorators like in good old RC4?

Thanks.

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule }   from '@angular/common';

import { CrisisService }        from './crisis.service';
import { CrisisDetailResolve }  from './crisis-detail-resolve.service';

import { CrisisCenterComponent }     from './crisis-center.component';
import { CrisisListComponent }       from './crisis-list.component';
import { CrisisCenterHomeComponent } from './crisis-center-home.component';
import { CrisisDetailComponent }     from './crisis-detail.component';

import { crisisCenterRouting } from './crisis-center.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    crisisCenterRouting
  ],
  declarations: [
    CrisisCenterComponent,
    CrisisListComponent,
    CrisisCenterHomeComponent,
    CrisisDetailComponent
  ],

  providers: [
    CrisisService,
    CrisisDetailResolve
  ]
})
export class CrisisCenterModule {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NgModule` was introduced to support lazy loading in combination with the router. Therefore if you want to lazy load a part of your application only when the related route is actually being navigated to, then this part of your application has to go into it's own `NgModule`.

Besides that `NgModule` can be used to group together components, directives, pipes, and services according to your preference. Common is to create an `NgModule` for components, directives, pipes, and services that built together a "feature" that you might want to reuse at different places.

You can also put everything that is not lazy loaded into a single `NgModule` if you want, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Thanks Gunter.  I didn't saw that information in the documentation. Or I miss something?

Comment: Did you check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html ? (it's a while I checked it myself so not sure what it contains exactly).

Comment: yes I read the Guide about NgModule but not the FAQ. Thanks, I'll check it.

Comment: So in FAQ I saw that I can't declare thirdparty modules. So should I use old *directives* way in pure component when I want to use some thirdparty popup (for example)?   like* @Component({..., directives: [customPopupDirective]})*

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to exactly. If found 2 mention of 3rd party but none seems to match your comment.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain more detailed. So let's imagine that I have some complicated component with child components, services and in that componnet some thirdparty will be used (and I woun't lazy load that component). So it can be a simple Component without NgModule wrapper as I understand  like at old RC4.  And to use that thirdparty popup, should I declare that popup directive inside my component via old directive way:   @Component({selector: 'test', template: `<custom_pop></custom_pop>`,directives: [customPopup]. Or I should create NgModule and IMPORT thirdparty to that NgModuile.

Comment: There is no `directives: []` in `@Component()` anymore. What you can do is to add the 3rd-party component to `declarations: []` of the `NgModule()` where you want to use it. If you want to use it in other `NgModule`s as well, then you need to import the `NgModule` where you added the 3rd-party component to `declarations`. If you don't want to import this `NgModule` because the other stuff it contains is unrelated to the module that also needs the 3rd-party component, then move the 3rd-party component to its own `NgModule` to make it reusable on its own.

Comment: Thanks so much Gunter.